# How to find and delete the duplciates on array of json

Tags: php, arrays, json, decode, encode

How can i find and delete the duplicates on

```
[{"id":"1","name":"raj"},{"id":"2","name":"antony"},{"id":"1","name":"raj"}]
```

Here How can i replace the duplicate entry i.e., `{"id":"1","name":"raj"}`

So, my output should be

```
[{"id":"1","name":"raj"},{"id":"2","name":"antony"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how you can do it

```
$j = '[{"id":"1","name":"raj"},{"id":"2","name":"antony"},{"id":"1","name":"raj"}]';
$ar = json_decode($j,true);
$unique = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $ar)));
echo json_encode($unique);
```

Result you will get as

```
[{"id":"1","name":"raj"},{"id":"2","name":"antony"}]
```